# Javascript operators in switch case

Tags: javascript, operators

I'm creating a panel and there are stats for memory, CPU and HDD. I'm using a `switch` statement and in the `case` method, I'm putting the current usage of CPU, memory and HDD.

However, the problem is that I'm using operators and I don't know which operator to use because I've tried all of them and I didn't get the results that I expected.

[image: example stats from the UI]

And this is the code: https://pastebin.com/YaxCm0Be

```js
                    switch(true){
                        case (mem_percent_get <= 0.01):
                            var mem_progress_color = 'progress-bar-primary';
                            break;
                        case (mem_percent_get <= 33):
                            var mem_progress_color = 'progress-bar-success';
                            break;
                        case (mem_percent_get <= 66):
                            var mem_progress_color = 'progress-bar-warning';
                            break;
                        case (mem_percent_get <=  80):
                            var mem_progress_color = 'progress-bar-danger';
                            break;
                         default:
                            mem_progress_color = 'progress-bar-theme';
                           
                           
                    }
                   
                    switch(true){
                        case (cpu_percent_get <= 33):
                            var cpu_progress_color = 'progress-bar-success';
                            break;
                        case (cpu_percent_get <= 66):
                            var cpu_progress_color = 'progress-bar-warning';
                            break;
                        case (cpu_percent_get <= 80):
                            var cpu_progress_color = 'progress-bar-danger';
                            break;
                         default:
                            cpu_progress_color = 'progress-bar-primary';
                           
                           
                    }
                   
                    switch(true){
                        case hdd_percent_get <= 0.01:
                            var hdd_progress_color = 'progress-bar-primary';
                            break;
                        case hdd_percent_get <= 30:
                            var hdd_progress_color = 'progress-bar-success';
                            break;
                        case hdd_percent_get <= 60:
                            var hdd_progress_color = 'progress-bar-warning';
                            break;
                        case hdd_percent_get <= 80:
                            var hdd_progress_color = 'progress-bar-danger';
                            break;
                         default:
                            hdd_progress_color = 'progress-bar-theme';
                    }
```

Comment: What do you percent values look like? Are they whole numbers or decimals? Does `50%` === `50` or `.5`?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda There are whole numbers. Percents are calculated with this formula https://pastebin.com/0gBhgXMx max and used are in MB.

Comment: Added answer for turning it into a reusable function

Comment: @MartinSholev Please consider posting a **demo** of your code instead of just a _pastebin_.

Answer (score -1):

Well, my first comment is to not use a `switch` in this case. What you are doing is essentially `if () { } else if() {}` blocks. You should be using `switch` when you have a value that you want to strictly check against. I suggest looking into at the MDN docs for [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Secondly, from what I can gather is that for the memory, you need it to be red when the value is 1696 / 2098 (80.83%). All of your if/elseif cases rely on `<=` which would mean that the value must be less than or equal to the number on the right of the equation. In your case, you are looking for `<= 80`, and without seeing how you calculate `mem_percent_get` (if it is in the pastebin, I'm unable to open that on my current network), you're value is likely above 80.

For your danger, you likely want 80-100+% as being red, so you should be using `>=` or greater than or equal to operator.

MDN has an excellent resources on [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Thanks, i correct the operator for 80+% using  Chase DeAnda method.

Answer (score -1):

Created a `getClassName` method that accepts a percent and will return a className:

```js
const getClassName = percent => {

  switch(true){
      case (percent <= 0.01):
          return 'progress-bar-primary';
      case (percent <= 33):
          return 'progress-bar-success';
      case (percent <= 66):
          return 'progress-bar-warning';
      case (percent <=  80):
          return 'progress-bar-danger';
      default:
          return 'progress-bar-theme';
  }

}

console.log('0: ', getClassName(0));
console.log('40: ', getClassName(40));
console.log('50: ', getClassName(50));
console.log('80: ', getClassName(80));
console.log('100: ', getClassName(100));
```

Comment: While this would reduce duplicated code (by removing the 3 `switch` statements), this doesn't solve the issue presented in the question based on the fact that the switch has not changed. Meaning the error indicated by the screenshot would still occur.

Comment: @JeremyDentel I see that you're making a lot of assumptions as to what OP is looking to do in your post. I'll let OP decide whether or not this is correct, and if not, provide more details on the expected behavior.

Comment: This method save lines of code. Thanks @ChaseDeAnda. Using switch statements with a lot of case can create a little delay(30/40 ms depends )